# Why does db.select<T> is so slow when the model inherits from AuditBase?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I can observe that fetching all records from a small table (100 records) can take 1600 miliseconds, even using a ":memory:" SQLite database.

This happens **only** when the model inherits from `AuditBase`; otherwise the performance is fast (around 8 miliseconds).

My test code is:

```cs
public class Record : AuditBase
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Table is created and pre-populated with 100 records:

```cs
using var db = appHost.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open();


if (db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Record>())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        db.Insert(new Record()
        {
            Name = $"Name {i}" ,
            
            CreatedBy =  "TEST",
            ModifiedBy = "TEST",
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                                     
        });
    }
}
```

Selecting the data from the service:

```cs
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; } = null!;
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        
        sw.Start();
        
        var records = Db.Select<Record>();
        
        var loadTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine($"Took {loadTime}ms to load {records.Count} records");

        return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
    }
}
```

The console output will read: `Took 1584ms to load 100 records`.

Why does it take so long?

Comment: DateTime's are very computationally expensive Data Type when performing TimeZone conversions, try using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

Comment: @mythz using UtcNow made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to repro this perf issue, I've created 2 programs, 1 which inherits AuditBase as done in this example at:

https://gist.cafe/fe8d04617ee1b061f24b0d8d56948119

[image]

Which shows it completes in **23ms**.

Whilst another example which replaces DateTime properties with long's to store Unix Timestamps to avoid DateTime conversions during Select at:
https://gist.cafe/a7c55a56842899a1ce34f11456027a9b

[image]

Which completes in roughly the same time at **21ms**.

Comment: Looks like this is someting related with JetBrains Rider.

The problem only occours when runing in Debug from Rider.

It's fine when running in Release, or after compiled.

In visual Studio 2022 the problem never occours.